# How is $K(x)$ pronounced, where $K$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field.  The ring of polynomials $K[x]$ is pronounced "$K$ adjoin $x$", right?  How is the field of rational functions $K(x)$ pronounced?

(Sorry if this is a silly question.  I am teaching an algebra class and I haven't heard these things spoken aloud since I was a student.)

Comment: It's called the field of rational functions of $x$. I know of no shorter name, but I'd never heard "$K$ adjoin $x$," either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Saying "the field of rational functions of $x$ (with coefficients in $K$)" every time one writes it on the blackboard seems like it would be tiring!  I would have guessed that people would find some abbreviated thing to say, out of laziness if for no other reason.

Comment: I would be very careful here: $K(x)$ can also mean field extension where $x\not\in K$ in which case *"x over K"*. I may have heard the same used over polynomials of $x$ over $K$ -- instead of teaching that one pronunciation is correct, I would tell students that $K[x]$, $K(x)$ ... can have different meanings and pronunciations depending on the country, area, etc